# Apple HomeKit SetUp Code

Tags: ios, homekit

I am working on Apple Home Kit Protocol (HAP), on the way to connecting my iPhone with IoT devices. I would like need you guys help to store setup code after HAP scan its. Is there any way I can do that?

```
func accessoryBrowser(_ browser: HMAccessoryBrowser, didFindNewAccessory accessory: HMAccessory) {
        listAccessory.append(contentsOf: [accessory])
    if accessory.name == "PREMIS 10:84:81" {    
        print (accessory.category)
        print (accessory)
        homeStore.home?.addAccessory(accessory, completionHandler: {error in
            if error != nil {
                print (error.debugDescription)
            } else {
                //I would like to catch the setup in here.
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
func accessoryBrowser(_ browser: HMAccessoryBrowser, didFindNewAccessory accessory: HMAccessory) {
        listAccessory.append(contentsOf: [accessory])
    if accessory.name == "PREMIS 10:84:81" {    
        print (accessory.category)
        print (accessory)
        homeStore.home?.addAccessory(accessory, completionHandler: {error in
            if error != nil {
                print (error.debugDescription)
            } else {
                homeStore.home?.assignAccessory(accessory, to: homeStore.home?.room, completionHandler: { 
                    error in
                    if error != nil {
                        print (error.debugDescription)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to test it since I'm not sure how you get your homeStore but it looks good to me

Comment: Could you please tell me more how it could help me to retrieve a setup code, a code that is labeled on your device? Thanks

Comment: After researching, I don't think we can read these setup code because there are something related to privacy.